# Символьная информация при сборке ядра Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel

Поступило такое задание, как собрать ядро Linux с и без символьной информации. Затем узнать объём самой символьной информации.

Но сколько интернета я не перерыл, у меня не вышло найти хоть сколько-нибудь толковую информацию по этому поводу (а на английском так понятия не имею, как называется та самая -символьная информация-).

Можете, пожалуйста, посоветовать какие-нибудь статьи по этому поводу или же дать информации?
(по большей части интересует, конечно, как включить/выключить символьную информацию, узнать её объём и что вообще такое эта символьная информация; однако за любую информацию буду премного благодарен)

---

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Символьная информация - это информация для дебаггинга (увеличивает вес ядра достаточно сильно; в моём случае с 11 Мб до 51 Мб).

Чтобы отключить её при сборке ядра, в файле `.config` нужно закомментировать строчку с переменной

`CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO`

Чтобы наоборот включить, нужно в том же файле `.config` прописать строчку

`CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y`

По сути дела, это же можно сделать красивее в `menuconfig`, но это уже другая история